# Domain not connecting to nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am running nginx on VPS, with Vultr's DNS configured as my nameservers. 
Here's my config file, with my site being `example.com`.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }


    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The nginx message is displayed at my VPS's IP, but not on my main domain.

Comment: There is `default` config of nginx which would handling the request when you are using IP. when you are using `www.example.com` it is coming to this block. And most probably you would have a index.php which is receiving the request and showing you some response, or it is erroring out

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks for the information. I think you're onto something, as I just noticed that I can connect to the domain via the domain's IP (not the VPS's) and I will get a response.

Comment: *Fixed, I guess it was just my browser